# deserialize nested complext types..c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

.NET 4.6.1

I have a json string:

```
{
"success": true,
"rows": [
    {
        "meter_id": "10443720003987688"
    }]
  }
```

Here's my class:

```
public class ESIIDClass
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Rows rows { get; set; }
}

public class Rows
{
    public string meter_id { get; set; }
}
```

I deserialize the string like so:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var esiid = json_serializer.Deserialize<ESIIDClass>(theJSONstring);
```

But this throws an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Type 'WebAPI.Controllers.Rows' is not
supported for deserialization of an array.
```

How do I deserialize nested complex types? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `Rows` be a collection as it is an array in the `JSON`?

Comment: JFYI: Maybe you should take a look at Newtonsoft.Json: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: @MartinParkin - yep..I changed rows to this public List<Rows> rows { get; set; } and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You class should be named Row, as it represents a single Row (it's not pural).

```
public class Row
```

In json, rows is clearly an array:

```
"rows": [
```

So your class should reflect that:

```
public Row[] rows { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
public class ESIIDClass
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Rows[] rows { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class ESIIDClass
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public List<Rows> rows { get; set; }
}
```

The json key-value pair's value with `[]` will map the C# type inherited from `IEnumerable`.